# Can anyone figure out how this code showing running error? It is printing infinite time -1 along with correct answer

Tags: c++, runtime-error, infinite-loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int subarraysum(int arr[],int n,int sum){
    int cur_sum=0,start=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

     cur_sum=cur_sum+arr[i];

    while(start<i && cur_sum>sum){
        cur_sum=cur_sum-arr[start];
        start++;
         }

    if(cur_sum==sum)
     {
         cout<<start<<" "<<i;
         return 1;
     }
    }
    cout<<"-1";
  //return 0;  
}
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int l=0;l<t;t++){
        int n,s;
    cin>>n>>s;
    int arr[n]={0};
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {cin>>arr[i];
    }

    subarraysum(arr, n, s);

    }
return 0;
}
```

This question is simple input output question but it is printing my answer and the infinite times -1 and i am not able to figure out the problem with this code and its running time error problem.

Comment: Good news, you don't need anyone's help to figure this out! You can do it yourself, you already have the tool to figure it out: your debugger. This is what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you already tried using your debugger, and if not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: What do you expect `cout<<"-1";` to do, if not to print `-1`? Note: Falling out of `subarraysum`, without `return` is undefined behavior (like you do when you `cout << "-1"`).

Comment: And prior to running into UB and debugging as to why, this program doesn't even compile due to the `int arr[n]={0};` declaration (`n` is not a constant expression here).

Comment: This: `for(int l=0;l<t;t++)` will be a loop that never ends; you probably mean this: `for(int l=0;l<t;l++)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is indeed tricky. You declare a function `int subarraysum(int arr[],int n,int sum)`. The problem here is the return statement. Your function **must** return a value, but your code does not, in this form. This leads to undefined behavior. The `int main()`-function in C++ is the only function in C++, which has a `non-void`-return value, that is allowed to not return anything.

Depending on the optimization level of your compiler this undefined behavior can result in an endless loop, even though the `for`-loop before seams to exit. Try to uncomment `return 0;` at the end of the function, this should do the job.

Btw. debugging your code will not help you here, because the behavior is different in debug-mode. There everything could be fine. Compile your code with all warnings on `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. The compiler will tell you that there could be a problem. Treat warnings like errors.